# runtime passing class name in C# mongodb

Tags: c#, mongodb

I am trying to pass my class name runtime for as below

```
Assembly a = Assembly.Load("Test.Model");
                    Type el = a.GetType("Test.Model.ClassName");

                    var myObj = Activator.CreateInstance(el);
                    var ab = db.GetCollection<Here I Want to pass class name>(Properties["ClassName"]);
```

the class name will be passed runtime.
How can I achive this.

So if my class name is ABC the code will be like

```
var ab = db.GetCollection<ABC>("ABC");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use reflection with

```
var methodInfo = db.GetType().GetMethod("GetCollection");
methodInfo = methodInfo.MakeGenericMethod(/*The type to put in*/);
methodInfo.Invoke(db, new object[] { Properties["ClassName"] });
```

Is this helping?